# How do I merge two different tables to a single table?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm making an android-Base Point of Sale System and I'm straggling of combining two tables , I want The Table Foods and The Table Drinks are combined in the Table Menu.

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FOODs.db";
//FOODs Tables name
public static final String TABLE_FOODS = "table_Food";
public static final String TABLE_DRINKS = "table_drinks";
public static final String TABLE_MENU = "table_data";


//FOODs Table Columns name
private static final String COL_1 = "Primary ID";
private static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
private static final String COL_3 = "PRICE";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CreateTableMains = "CREATE TABLE " +  TABLE_FOODS + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            " NAME TEXT, PRICE TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CreateTableMains);

    String CreateTableDrinks = "CREATE TABLE " +  TABLE_DRINKS + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            " NAME TEXT, PRICE TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CreateTableDrinks);

    String CreateTable = "CREATE TABLE " +  TABLE_MENU + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            " NAME TEXT, PRICE TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CreateTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FOODS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DRINKS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MENU);
```

Comment: You can use the `UNION` operator to combine different queries into a single result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge tables using [**UNION** - see *Compound Select Statements about 3/4 down*](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) between SELECTS

```
 SELECT * FROM table_Food UNION SELECT * FROM table_drinks
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table_Food UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table_drinks
```

Both would work the same UNLESS you happened to have a drink and food that had the same name, the same price and the same id. Without ALL the duplicate rows would be omitted. As such UNION ALL is safer.

- The above assumes that you want all columns.
- Note the column counts from each select must match

  - but you can easily get around that e.g. `SELECT *,1 as extracolumn FROM table_Food` adds a new column to the result

**IF** what you want is to just use the one table **table_data** then
to load the data from both the table_food AND the table_drinks table into the table_Data you could use :-

```
INSERT INTO table_data (name,price) SELECT name,price FROM table_Food UNION ALL SELECT name,price FROM table_Drinks;
```

- id's are omitted as being a Primary Key if the values were the same then the above would fail due to a UNIQUE constraint conflict.
- There will very likely be duplicate id's as you have INTEGER PRIMARY KEY for the id column. This makes the column an alias of the rowid column (a hidden column) which has the  attribute of generating a value unique to the table initially 1, then 2 then 3 (but not guaranteed). The AUTOINCREMENT keyword adds an additional twist in that the unique value must be greater then any that exist or have been used.

If you want to temporarily merge all 3 tables then you could use:-

```
SELECT * FROM table_Food UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table_drinks UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table_Data;
```

If you wanted to merge all three and know what came from which table you could use :-

```
SELECT *,'Food' FROM table_Food UNION ALL SELECT *,'Drinks' FROM table_drinks UNION ALL SELECT *,'Menu' FROM table_Data;
```

[SQL Fiddle demo of the above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/5ed80/1)

Comment: So if I use UNION ALL  It happen that all the data  from the table Foods and table Drinks, like Name and Price are merge in to  the table menu?

Comment: No they are temporarily merged in the result set (Cursor) Oops missed that bit. Will amend the answer to cover.

Comment: public Cursor showMenuData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FOODS + "UNION ALL SELECT * FROM "  + TABLE_DRINKS );
        return data;
    } I having an error  I think I didn't declared UNION ALL correctly

Comment: You missed a space between table name and UNION. However, answer updated to place all rows in the menu table.

Comment: So  if there's a possible that I add foreign ID so that it make all data has a different ID when I merge into the Table menu?

Comment: @Potpoopow if you see the answer the INSERT INTO omits the id and thus when the row is inserted into the Table menu (see and try the fiddle link) different id's will be assigned. All that a foreign key does is add a rule saying that the child value must be a value in the parent. Foreign keys don't do any manipulation of values (other than onDelete/onUpdate which can keep the child values in line with the parent if the parent changes).

Comment: public boolean addDataFoods (String Name, String Price){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,Name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,Price);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_FOODS,  null, contentValues);

        if (result == -1 ) {
            return false;
        } else{
            return true;
        }
    }

Comment: I have that method for inserting a data for table foods and table drinks so how can I change the INSERT INTO but same output like in the fiddle demo on the third table?

Comment: You need to add a column e.g. type. so `String CreateTable = "CREATE TABLE " +  TABLE_MENU + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            " NAME TEXT, PRICE TEXT, TYPE TEXT)";` You can then use `INSERT INTO table_data (name,price,type) SELECT name,price,'Food' FROM table_Food UNION ALL SELECT name,price,'Drinks' FROM table_Drinks;`

Comment: @Potpoopow demo re the previous comment at [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e88155/1)

Comment: public Cursor MergeData (){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(" INSERT INTO " + TABLE_MENU (name,price,type) "SELECT name,price, 'Food' FROM " + TABLE_FOODS, " UNION ALL SELECT name,price 'Drink' FROM " + TABLE_DRINKS;
        "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MENU);
        return  data;           I have a error when I declared this method, how do I declare this correctly?

Comment: @Potpoopow you've omitted the `,` (comma) between price and 'Drink' and have  a comma before  `" UNION ALL ......"` that should not be there it should be a +

Comment: how about (name,type,price)?

Comment: @Potpoopow you should be working things like that out for yourself. Experiment using SQL Fiddle or get an SQLite Tool such as DB Browser for SQlite. The rule is basically that the columns specified after INSERT INTO determines the order that the selected data should be in. So if you use INSERT INTO (name,type,price) then the first value from the SELECT's will be placed into the name column, the second value into the type column and so on. So without changing the order of the selects you would place the name in the name column a and the price in the type column.

Comment: public Cursor MergeData (){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(" INSERT INTO " + TABLE_MENU  (name,price,type) + " SELECT name, price,'Food' FROM " + TABLE_FOODS +  " UNION ALL SELECT name,price, 'Drink' FROM " + TABLE_DRINKS +
        " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MENU, null);           Please help me what do I need to declare to fix the error in (name,price,type)